# Undefined reference when changing from GCC 4.6 to 4.7

Tags: c++, static, c++11, constants

I had to switch from g++-4.6 to 4.7 (so I can use some C++11 features). Now, the compiler complains:

`In function WordJIT<float>::WordJIT(): undefined reference to JitRegType<float>::Val_t`

I am wondering if something has changed between these compiler version that can affect symbol resolving. Or is the language better implemented in the new version (4.7) and what I am doing is wrong: (same code compiles with 4.6)

### jit.h

```
class Jit {
  public:
    enum RegType { f32=0,f64=1,u16=2,u32=3,u64=4,s16=5,s32=6,s64=7 };
  // ...
};

template <class T> struct JitRegType {};
template <> struct JitRegType<float>  { static const Jit::RegType Val_t = Jit::f32; };
```

### wordjit.h

```
  #include "jit.h"

  template<class T>
  class WordJIT 
  {
    WordJIT() {
      mapReg.insert( std::make_pair( JitRegType<T>::Val_t , jit.getRegs( JitRegType<T>::Val_t , 1 ) ) );
    }
    private:
      typedef std::map< Jit::RegType , int > MapRegType;
      mutable MapRegType mapReg;
  };
```

### Edit:

Is `static const` okay in a header file or should one use `constexpr` ?

Is there a way to declare also `Val_t` in the class declaration of `JitRegType` but not actually define it ?

Comment: what is `reg` in `reg( JitRegType<T>::Val_t );` ?

Comment: @PiotrNycz I substituted it for a placeholder to not blow the example too much. But, see above

Comment: Do you get the error when just switching to gcc 4.7 but stayed at C++03 or did you also enable C++11? Because name resolving should be implemented exactly the same in both versions if you choose the same C++ standard version, as they *should* implement it according to the standard.

Comment: `-std=c++0x` enabled in both 4.6 and 4.7. I need C++11 features in general in other parts of the code. Now I am using constructor delegation - the reason for switching to 4.7

Comment: Okay. I think this is a linker error? Did you try moving the definition of the static consts in some cpp file? Maybe the standard changed something. Maybe C++0x in 4.7 is C++11, while C++0x in 4.6 is something different. You can also try to define `Val_t` as an enum value, a common alternative to static const.

Comment: @leemes If I move the definitions to the `jit.cc` file, the compiler complains because it doesn't know anything about `Val_t`. Which makes sense. `template <class T> struct JitRegType {};` doesn't tell it of `Val_t`.

Comment: You're right. Did you try the enum trick?

Comment: Also, I just checked with `nm` there is no `JitRegType` in `jit.o` when moving the definitions to `jit.cc`

Comment: I think I can't use `enum` because its not an integral type but `Jit::RegType` that is the underlying type

Comment: I mean `template <> struct JitRegType<float>  { enum { Val_t = Jit::f32 }; };`, while keeping the rest of the code the same. This *should* be possible, but I'm no template expert at all...

Comment: I think I will get into a type nightmare then. Your suggestion doesn't include the required type `Jit::RegType`. But I will try (but I guess that is what I tried first)

Comment: @leemes This what you get then: `no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘JitRegType<float>::<anonymous enum>’ to ‘Jit::RegType’`

Comment: Dirty workaround: Make `reg(...)` accept an int instead of an `RegType`, or cast it. But it would be better if someone knows the reason why this worked in 4.6 and doesn't in 4.7...

Comment: Indeed! My workaround is now: Avoid introducing the named type `RegType`, using anonymous enums and `int` as the type (as you suggested).

Comment: Glad we have an explanation for this issue now (Very interesting...). You can now use your typed argument again, giving nicer code ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per 9.4.2p3:

> If a non-volatile *const static* data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* [...] The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an *initializer*.

So you need to add to your program (probably in `jit.cpp`):

```
const Jit::RegType JitRegType<float>::Val_t;
```

This is so that if the `static const` member is used in a context where a reference to it is required, there exists a unique definition for the linker to refer to (the same as any `static` member that is not a member of a class template or class template partial specialization).

The issue is discussed in depth [on the gcc wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/VerboseDiagnostics#missing_static_const_definition).

Note that both gcc 4.6 and 4.7 are behaving sensibly; it is just that gcc 4.6 chooses to inline the value of `JitRegType<float>::Val_t` where gcc 4.7 chooses not to (or possibly is inlining it but emitting a linker reference to the definition as well).  It's a little difficult to tell whether the implementation is required to issue a diagnostic; 9.4.2p3 describes a diagnosable rule but then 9.4.2p4 (implicitly referring to non-`const` `static` data members) says that a diagnostic is not required.  Either way, as a quality of implementation issue it's better that a compiler issue a diagnostic than not.

Comment: @Frank gcc 4.6 is inlining the value (it has access to it from the header) and not emitting a linker reference to it.  Strictly speaking your program is ill-formed without the definition, even if gcc 4.6 compiles it.

Comment: Wow! This is important to know. Might break lots of code when switching to 4.7 which obviously implements the language more strictly. Many thanks!!